# PHP Project Cleanup

Tags: php

I have a fairly large PHP project that I recently did a ton of refactoring on. This isn't a 'spaghetti code' situation but more so a 'wait a minute.. what files in this project are actually used?'

Is there an easy way to (similar to checking for code coverage?) pare down the file structure to only the files that are in use, or will I need to write some more code to determine that?

TLDR: I'm wondering if there's a tool that will keep track of what files are used in a project and what aren't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method (among many I'd guess). **This is not production ready** - just a hackish tool for you to assemble a list that you can parse out later. Or an idea you can take and make more robust.

create a php file in a directory

**tracker.php**

```
<?php
  $file = '/tmp/php-used.txt'; // or whatever location/filename
  $add = dirname(__FILE__)."\n";
  file_put_contents($file, $add, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Then add this to the top of every page. Make it consistent so if you want to remove it en-masse, you can do a global search/replace

```
<?php require('/path-to-file/tracker.php');?>
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was thinking about! Thank you so much. Now at least I know I am on the right path.